# Tomcat server sends 404 error when hitting the url

Tags: java, gradle, tomcat, build.gradle

I have a Spring application. I'm trying to run it on localhost:8080 using gradle. This is the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'org.gretty' version '3.0.5'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    gretty 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.54'
}

gretty {
    httpPort = 8080  // Port on which the embedded Tomcat server will listen
    contextPath = '/'  // Context path for your application
    servletContainer = 'tomcat9'  
}
```

This is the web.xml configuration:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
     
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>V2_GACD</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.V2_GACDServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>V2_GACD</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v2_gacd</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This starts the Tomcat server, but when I access the url `http://localhost:8080/`, it gives me a 404 error. But when I ran the same in app engine, it was showing the index.jsp page as soon as the base url is hit. What could be the issue?

Edit:
This is the file that has the code that will return a jsp page

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.fullauth.api.enums.OauthResponseType;
import com.fullauth.api.exception.TokenResponseException;
import com.fullauth.api.model.oauth.OauthAccessToken;
import com.fullauth.api.service.FullAuthOauthService;
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONArray;
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;
import com.service.AgentHelper;
//import com.service.CallData;
import com.service.GoClockService;
//import com.service.PMF;
import com.service.RequestHandler;
import com.service.StackTraceWriter;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.*;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File; 

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/AgentInfoAction")
public class AgentInfoAction {
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle("ApplicationResources");
    String sb_path = resourceBundle.getString("sb.domain.name");

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AgentInfoAction.class
            .getPackage().getName());
    
    static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    static {
        mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, true);

        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
                true);
        mapper.configure(
                DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(
                JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/saveAgentInfo")
    public String saveAgentInfo(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
//      String agent = req.getParameter("agent");
        String state = req.getParameter("state");
//      String readypercent = req.getParameter("readypercent");
//      String agentname = req.getParameter("agentname");
//      String v2login = req.getParameter("v2login");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String sessionId = req.getParameter("sessionId");
        String _uniquePin = req.getParameter("uniquePin") == null ? req
                .getParameter("uniquepin") : req.getParameter("uniquePin");
        String _eventLongTime = req.getParameter("eventTime") == null ?  String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) : req.getParameter("eventTime");//req.getParameter("eventLongTime");
        //String _eventLongTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) ;  
        String clockingStatus = req.getParameter("clockingStatus");
        String contactId = req.getParameter("contactId");
        String response = "";
        //logger.info("req is : "+req);
        //logger.info("isMissedStatus --=> "+req.getParameter("isMissedStatus"));
        
        String serverAccessToken = new AgentHelper().getOauthAccessTokenWithJWT().getAccessToken();
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> userMetaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            userMetaData.put("country", req.getHeader("X-AppEngine-Country"));
            userMetaData.put("region", req.getHeader("X-AppEngine-Region"));
            userMetaData.put("city", req.getHeader("X-AppEngine-City"));
            userMetaData.put("latlong",
                    req.getHeader("X-AppEngine-CityLatLong"));
            response = new GoClockService().trackEvent(state,
                    req.getRemoteAddr(), email, sessionId,
                    userMetaData, _uniquePin, _eventLongTime, clockingStatus,contactId,serverAccessToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/ccpView")
    public String ccpView(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "mainpage";
    }
```

```
`mainpage` will return the index.jsp page. Works fine for app engine. Even tried to hit the exact url with /AgentInfoAction/ccpView at the end of localhost:8080, nothing seems to be working
```

Comment: Are you sure that that contextPath value for gretty actually works? Where does your application physically end up at runtime?

Comment: @nitind It's supposed to render a jsp page

Comment: @nitind I've edited the question, please verify